# Unrecognized option: I picard.jar

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq, picard

I am trying to convert a BMA file into FASTQ format, using picard.jar. This is my command:

```
java -jar /opt/picard-tools/picard.jar SamToFastq \ I=chr2chr3.bam \ FASTQ=chr2chr3.f1.fastq \ SECOND_END_FASTQ=chr2chr3.f2.fastq
```

However I got this error message:

> ERROR: Unrecognized option:  I

I am totally confused, Any thoughts?

Comment: humorous comment: Maybe you need to call the USS enterprise :-) .

Comment: what are those backslashes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the backslashes

```
java -jar /opt/picard-tools/picard.jar SamToFastq  I=chr2chr3.bam  FASTQ=chr2chr3.f1.fastq  SECOND_END_FASTQ=chr2chr3.f2.fastq
```

note:

- you can compress the fastqs, ignore the small errors in the BAM

  java -jar /opt/picard-tools/picard.jar SamToFastq  I=chr2chr3.bam  FASTQ=chr2chr3.f1.fastq.gz  SECOND_END_FASTQ=chr2chr3.f2.fastq.gz  VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT
- for bioinformatics questions, you'd better ask https://www.biostars.org/ or http://seqanswers.com/forums/search.php?do=getnew

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
java -jar /opt/picard-tools/picard.jar SamToFastq \ 'I=chr2chr3.bam' \ FASTQ=chr2chr3.f1.fastq \ SECOND_END_FASTQ=chr2chr3.f2.fastq
```